Can I recover a corrupted local Git repository
Hoping someone can help with this.  I'll freely admit I'm no Git expert, so there might be some false assumptions in the following.
We use Git for source control and the SourceTree GUI as a front end.  Yesterday, while I was working, our corporate antivirus software (Sentinal One) identified Source Tree as a potential threat and blocked it.  Subsequently, it popped up a toaster notification saying that it had fixed it.  I don't know exactly what it did, but it left my local Git repo in a corrupted state.  A bunch of source files are missing and the .git folder was missing several necessary files (Head, Fetch_Head, Orig_Head, config and index).  The repo is no longer available in Source tree and a "Git Branch" was reporting that it wasn't a valid Git repository.  I've taken a copy of my corrupted repo so at least I know I can get back to this point if things I try make things worse.
On the off chance, I tried copying a HEAD file from an unrelated repo and this seemed to fix the Git Branch issue.  It now reports as a valid directory and reports some of my branches.  What it doesn't report is two branches which I was only holding locally (I didn't want to push them to remote until they were production ready) which represent a significant amount of work.  I could just reclone from the central repository, but I'll lose those branches as they were never pushed.
I've run a Git reflog against the directory and I can see various actions I took moving to and from those branches, so it looks like the log is still complete.  On the off chance I tried a git checkout of the feature, but this reports that it "did not match and file(s) known to Git".  Finally, I tried a git fsck and that reports an error: refs/heads/feature/myfeature invalid reflog entry followed by a bunch of missing blobs and dangling commits and trees.  So my local feature is still known about in some form.
My best guess is that the actual source is still held somewhere in the repository, but the sudden blocking of source tree has caused the meta data to become corrupted.  I've found some posts that explain how to automatically prune the source data so that it matches the meta data but I think I want the opposite.  I want to rebuild the meta data from the source data.
Is that possible?  Is there anything anyone can suggest that might help me recover.  (Apologies for the length of the post, but I wanted to put out as much info as I could)

I know it's not what you want to hear right now, but it's probably what you need to hear: "I didn't want to push them to remote until they were production ready" is a bad idea: push early, push often. You can have your own private branch with stupid "do stuff" commit messages and clean it up when it's "ready". There's no point in being cautious about committing/pushing.

If it's the anti-virus that messed up your repo, have you checked if it has put all the missing file in the quarantine and that they could be easily restored?

Answers about recovery of blobs or maybe to a lesser extent commits could be of some help.

Regarding commit frequency: You should never be more than 2 minutes away from checking in and going home.

And with regards to pushing your local repository to somewhere else for backup you can do that privately and "hidden" assuming that you have access to a network disk (and assuming some IT department keeps it backed up). While you could clone your /home/username/src/someproject  repository to the network disk and add it as a remote, you would then have a "noise" remote in your work repo. To avoid this you can instead add your work repo as a remote in your /mnt/server/some/where/repoclone repo and run pull changes inside that repo (can easily be put into a backup-my-repos.sh script).


I tried a git fsck and that reports an error: refs/heads/feature/myfeature invalid reflog entry followed by a bunch of missing blobs and dangling commits and trees.

If git fsck reported missing blobs from your local feature branch, chances are that your data is lost. A blob object is the binary representation of the content of a committed file. If blob objects are missing from the object store of a repository, then Git is not able to reconstruct the commits whose tree points to those blobs.
In your case, it might be that the blobs of your local changes are still intact, and that git fsck is signaling missing blobs belonging to commits reachable from before the divergence of your branch. In that case, you could recover your local changes, re-download your repository, re-create your feature branch, and then apply the recovered changes.
One thing you could also try is to check if your antivirus has still those files. Hopefully, they haven't been deleted, but only removed and put in quarantine. You could add the path of your repository in the antivirus exceptions, and restore the files from the quarantine.

Recovering data from Blob Objects
I'm extending my answer since I deem more appropriate to include this piece of information here and especially after reading your comment:

So I can probably do some detective work seeing if the objects referenced in the logs

I don't think that using git log (I'm assuming that's what you meant) might help you with what you need. What you could do is explore the .git/objects folder (your object store) and filter for anything whose Date created is greater than the date of when you started your local modifications.
Once you've filtered out the objects you're not interested in, you can use git cat-file with the -t option to understand if the object in question is a blob or not git cat-file -t <SHA1>. If it is, you can run git cat-file blob <SHA1> to read its content. Of course, a script that automatizes this process might be more suited if you have tens or hundreds of objects to inspect.
Also, keep in mind that the name you see for the files contained in .git/objects is not their full SHA1. In fact, for file system optimization, Git breaks the SHA1 of its objects into two: a 2 character part and a 38 character part. The first two characters are used to create a subfolder in .git/objects, while the remaining 38 characters are used to name the file associated to an object. The file is also placed under its corresponding subfolder, and the combination of the two gives you the object's full SHA1.
For example, an object's file named deb84adf9386d2ff33a577ab20bb207efd7e0a and placed under the subfolder af has a full SHA1 of afdeb84adf9386d2ff33a577ab20bb207efd7e0a. Like so, with a first level of subfolders, Git doesn't have thousands of files right under .git/objects, improving performances when accessing to its files.

"If git fsck reported missing blobs from your local feature branch, chances are that your data is lost. " I think I might have found a clue about this though I'm not sure.  If I browse to .git\refs\heads\feature I do not see my local branches - implying the reference the blob is missing.  If I browse to .git\logs\refs\heads\feature I see my branches and if I open one in notepad++ it's human readable and I can see all my commits in there.  So the log of changes exists even if the ref and/or blobs doesn't.  I'm guessing the blobs are under the objects folder somewhere?

"In that case, you could recover your local changes, re-download your repository, re-create your feature branch, and then apply the recovered changes.  "How would I recover the local changes (assuming they exist)?

"check if your antivirus has still those files" I'm trying to find out but its managed from the US and I'm in the UK so there's a delay.  I don't think so though.  If I look at the anti virus client I've got on my machine it shows it blocking SourceTree but makes no mention of the missing files.  I think what happened was that the antivirus blocked SourceTree while it was mid switch between branches.  So the antivirus didn't actually delete them itself, it just started a chain of events that ended up there.

@FunkyDexter Answer 1: a branch is merely a ref to a commit, it does not contain data. It's just a file with the SHA1 of the commit is point to (usually the HEAD commit of a branch). If you want to recover the objects of your repository you need to go under ".git/objects". Answer 2: there are several tools online for data recovering, I don't think I'm allowed to disclose them, as the platform prohibits advertising. A quick google search should do the trick.

Answer 3: when you switch from a branch to another, there is no saving. So even if you're blocked mid-switch, you will have at most a corrupted working directory, not a corrupted repository. Those objects already exist and are still intact in your object store. Something else must have happened for sure if git fsck is telling you that some objects are missing. It might be your antivirus quarantining your repository's files (never heard of, but could be), or something else that has erased your objects. It definitely cannot be being interrupted during a branch switch.

Thanks for the responses.  This is a great help in understanding.
Answer 1 - That's what I thought.  So I can probably do some detective work seeing if the objects referenced in the logs still exist in the objects folder and what the differential is.
Answer 2 - Ah, I didn't realise you were talking about Data Recovery tools, I thought it was an operation in GitHub.  That's not something I can do myself but I can certainly put it to IT Support.  Good idea, thanks.
Answer 3 - So maybe they're in quarantine somewhere.  Fingers crossed.

@FunkyDexter I've extended my answer after reading your last comment: "So I can probably do some detective work seeing if the objects referenced in the logs". Hope it will help you more with your problem.
